# Can we bring unification results under cofibrations outside?

Tags: cubical-type-theory, unification

Say we have an elaborator which supports metavariables and solve them on flex-rigid cases (with the obvious occurrence checking and scope checking). If we do such unification under a cofibration, do we still get correct results? To put it more formally, when we do something like
$$
\Gamma,\varphi \vdash ~?\equiv v:A
$$
where $?$ is a metavariable generated during type checking outside of $\varphi$, and $v$ is a well-typed term of type $A$. Can we solve $?$ to $v$ and bring the solution to the place where it is generated, which does not have $\varphi$ in the context?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you're talking about, but perhaps you're asking whether weakening is valid in your setup.

Comment: In what sense is this a question about cubical type theory, rather than simple/dependent type theory?

Comment: @Couchy ordinary type theory does not have judgments under a cofibration.

Comment: I am not an expert in cubical stuff, but if I understand correctly, you run the risk of a non-unique solution: what if ? should have a value which is more general than v, but collapses to v in the particular φ you are looking at? The analogy I have in mind is when you generate a predicate `?P` as the return type of a dependent if. In the `true` branch, you can try and instantiate `?P` with the type inferred for the branch, but doing this you force `?P` to be constant, and might get a spurious error in the `false` branch…

Comment: And also, as @Andrej remarked, is it possible that you v only makes sense in φ? If this is the case, then the metavariable which should make sense outside of φ cannot possibly be instantiated with v. Although I would rather call this a failure of strengthening (removing bits of the context), rather than weakening (extending the context).

Comment: I had no idea I remarked that. I sound very smart.